# How do I compare two tables with the same column definitions in different schemas?

Tags: db2

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm leading my projects initiative to upgrading our ETL software. This can result in data integrity differences. My testing plan is as follows:

1. create an identical schema, schema B, with the same table definitions as schema A
2. run all the ETL jobs to populate schema B using the upgraded ETL version
3. **compare the two schemas and record differences
4. determine why those differences occured

**So my question is regarding step 3. What technically do I need to do (commands, queries, etc) to compare every field in every row between the two schemas to confirm that they are identical?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you asking for if the data changed? or if the DDL changed?

Comment: I'm asking this for if data changes

Comment: How many tables/rows are there ? If not many you can get the data and compare it in file diff tools like Araxis manually otherwise you can write a small program to compare based on some prior information like which values are same for sure and which can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to do a quick check, you can always use EXCEPT in you query to identify if rows in 2 tables are identical.

```
SELECT 'TABLE1-ONLY' AS SRC, T1.*
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1
      EXCEPT
      SELECT * FROM TABLE2
      ) AS T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE2-ONLY' AS SRC, T2.*
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM TABLE2
      EXCEPT
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1
      ) AS T2
WITH UR;
```

If you are using Toad, it has data compare features as well.